# WPF two panel app - reuse or create new instance of panel VM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application whose main window contains two panels. The layout is pretty standard. The left panel is a a list of objects.  The right panel displays information about the object selected in the left panel.

Right now I have the left panel directly in the XAML of the window, although I'm thinking it should be its own UC/View.  The right panel is coded as a UC. The ViewModel for the main window has a field that is the VM for the right panel (call it the properties VM). The properties VM encapsulates the data for the selected object from the model.

When a different object is selected in the left panel I see two options:
1) Instantiate a new instance of the properties VM and load the corresponding data from the model 
2) Load the corresponding data from the model to the existing properties VM, and issue appropriate change notifications [My current implementation]

Is there an advantage or preferred way of doing things between the two options above?  Am I missing a better third option?
* Edit * Maybe a better question is - what are the advantages and disadvantages of the two methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a very standard scenario in the MVVM world. I believe you have a slight architectural issue that when resolved would make this question moot. The 'list' from where you are making your selection should *already* be a list of view models that wrap the 'object' a.k.a model. The properties view should simply be databound to the selected VM.

Comment: OK, I'm with you on the list being a list of VMs and not M objects.  I have seen that done before. So the user selects an object, or rather a VM wrapping that object.  Then on the right pane how do I tie the view to the selected VM?

Comment: You set the a source property that the right pane is bound to, to the selected object.

Comment: @mm8 - Thanks.  I figured that was the case, but wasn't thinking it all the way through.  When I first asked for clarification I was thinking in the context of the left pane VM (where the list item VMs live, and who doesn't have access to the right pane).  I belatedly realized  the window VM has visibility to both sides and serves as the link.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an advantage or preferred way of doing things between the two options above?

Not really, but it's probably simpler to just create a new instance and set the data-bound property to this instance instead of trying to re-use and update the state of an existing instance each time the button is clicked.

If you need to cache instances, you could use an IoC container or a custom cache container that resolves the instances for you. You could for example set up the container to always return the same instance of the same class or return a new instance each time depending on your requirements.

But there is "preferred way" really. Your requirements decide what would be the best way to solve your specific issue or use case.